# Remove page numbering from a section break

Tags: openxml, page-numbering

Does anybody have a clue about how to remove the page numbering from a section break in a word 2007 doc?

I have to put 3 documents together

- 1st part contains the page numbering and the formatting
- 2nd part ends takes the numbering from the 1st part and continues it. It ends with a section break(next page)
- 3rd page also takes the numbering (the numbering starts from 1) and I don't want that.

The last part contains some covers and other info pages and I don't want any numbering on them.

The 2nd and 3rd parts were inserted using `AltChunk`. I've tried locking the 3rd part for editing, i've tried putting a white rectangle over the footer, in front of the text, i've tried putting a section break (continuous) at the beginning of the 3rd part...all for nothing. The 3rd part simply adopts the same footer as the previous parts.

Can you please give me any feedback, ideas on how to find a solution or a workaround?